# My non-wordpress website showing a index of with a wordpress icon?

Tags: html, wordpress

I know there were many questions about removing the "index of" thingy, but mine is a bit specific. The index of page only shows when I try to access my website via desktop(it does show the homepage once i refresh the index of page), while it works normal on mobile.
Also, for some reason, there's a WordPress icon showing and i'm not using wordpress at all!
It was installed before, but removed via softaculous.
I do have a index.html page in my directory, and i've put the DirectoryIndex index.html inside of my .htaccess file already.

Comment: Show your HTML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your browser cached the favicon of your old site, and the browser keep think it the same site so it's not check new favicon.

Try to add different `favicon.ico` to your site and then try force refresh with `Ctrl + F5` or `Shift + F5` (browser will refresh with remove cache first).